# Smooth object fade in/slide up when page scrolled?

Tags: jquery, html

I just visit a website demo and found a cool effect. this is the site http://www.themefocus.co/alterna/newdemo/. When i scroll down the page, some object will show with fade in/slide up effect smoothly. What script does used there? Please help me, i'm very interest to that effect... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bootstrap theme,
To see it follow the steps:
1) Install Firebug in Firefox
2) Open your demo site

A Firebug window will get open..

3) Go to "Script" tab

Here you will find all the Js which are used for this demo.

Answer (score 0):

do this jquery may workout

```
<body><h1 class="demo">Top Header/Html</h1><p>Hello</p></body>
<script>
var scrollposition = $(".demo").scrollTop();
if(scrollposition == 400)
{
   //fade in/slide up do what you want
 }
</script>
```